# Cannot find symbol method

Tags: java, scope, local-variables, class-variables

Upon compiling, I get the error of **cannot find symbol - method add(java.lang.String)**. The goal of the code so far is just to add a new flavour to the `ArrayList`. I am using the BlueJ IDE, monstrous I know!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IceCream
{
    // stores ice cream flavours.
    private ArrayList<String> flavours;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class IceCream
     */
    public IceCream()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        flavours = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Method to add a flavour to the list.
     */
    public void newFlavour(String flavours)
    {
        flavours.add(flavours);        
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using the name `flavours` for everything in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named the String parameter equal to the attribute's name (flavours), so the compiler tries to lookup the add() method in the String class (which is not available). Change the code like:

```
public void newFlavour(String flavours)
{
    this.flavours.add(flavours);        
}
```

or use different names.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code:

```
public void newFlavour(String flavours)
{
    flavours.add(flavours);        
}
```

The parameter `flavours` is [shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) your field `flavours`, so the compiler is trying to find an `add` method in `String`, not `ArrayList`. You *could* just explicitly qualify it (`this.flavours.add(flavours)`) but it would be *much* better to change the parameter name. After all, you're not adding multiple flavours - just one... so your parameter name should reflect that:

```
public void newFlavour(String flavour)
{
    flavours.add(flavour);
}
```

And possibly change the method name to `addFlavour`, too.